# Baldur's Gate II config utility not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, baldurs-gate-2

Downloaded the BGII demo, just to see if I could run the game. Turns out that the configuration utlility shows up like this: 
[image: It's cut off]

As you can see, the window is too small for the info contained. So not only can I not select the options to make it run optimally, I can't get the game to run at all, because the wrong options are default. I can't resize the thing (not even through right-click->maximize), nor can I tab through the different areas, nor can I highlight and drag to get the rest of the window to show. Any ideas?

UPDATE: This the non-enhanced original version of the game from 2000.

Comment: What's your DPI setting? If you go into Display Settings > Resolution > Make text smaller or larger, and set that to 100% (smallest) does that fix it?

Comment: Should we assume this is the HD version and not the original?

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! The text setting was set to 150, which at my display setting means I don't have to squint to read something.

Comment: Why are you concerned that you can't run a 15 year old game? is your machine from the 90s?

Comment: In case you're concerned that your machine is too recent to run the game, I suggest you wait for the Steam Summer Sale and pick up the enhanced edition at a discount.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I think the issue is more "my PC is too new to run the game" than "my PC is too old to run the game" :D

Answer (score 2):

Since it got answered in comments, I thought I'd post what the comment said in an answer.

This problem was due to the DPI settings of the user, in Display Settings > Resolution > Make text smaller or larger. The OP had his text settings set to 150% so normal text was bigger. After he set it to 100%, it was fixed.